# How do I get promises to work in the right order in a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, node-mysql2

I'm trying to make a system that generates a radom ID number for a user and then checks if it is already in the mysql database. If it is then it will generate a new ID and check that against the database. It will continue this until it generates a unique identifier and return it to outside the function. I'm pretty new to JavaScript, Node and Asynchronous functions so I don't really know what I'm doing.

I've tried using promises, but the function always just returns "undefined" and checkChatIdExists doesn't finish until afterwards.

generateId() simply returns a 19 digit string and con is a database connection made with MySQL2

```
function checkChatIdExists(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        con.query("SELECT id FROM messages WHERE id = " + id, (err, result)=>{
            if(err !== null) { console.log(err) };
            if(result.length == 0) {
                resolve(id);  //newly generated id is okay
            } else {
                reject("ID was not Unique");         //newly generated id was not okay
            }
        })
    })
}

async function generateChatId() {
    
    async function generateAndCheckIdValid() {
        let id = await generateId();
        console.log("ID generated - " + id);
        checkChatIdExists(id).then((validId) => {
            return validId;       
        }).catch((message) => {
            console.log(message);
            return generateAndCheckIdValid();            //if id does exist then run again
        })
    }

    let id = await generateAndCheckIdValid();
    return id;
}
```

Comment: generateAndCheckIdValid Only has a return statement in the catch section.

Comment: Don't use `.then()` for `checkChatIdExists()`; use `await`.

Comment: Change `checkChatIdExists(id).then((validId) => {` to `return checkChatIdExists(id).then((validId) => {`

Comment: Side note: mysql2 also supports a promise wrapper, check its docs. If you use that, you can simplify your `checkChatIdExists` function to `if (await con.query(......)) { return id } else { throw new Error('ID was not unique') }`. Also, I'm assuming `id` may come from a user - and you are not protected against SQL injection! Instead of embedding `id` into the query, use a parameter: `con.query('SELECT id FROM messages WHERE id = ?', [id])` - or use [`sql-template-strings`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql-template-strings): `sql\`SELECT id FROM messages WHERE id = ${id}\``.

Comment: (Preemptive comment to people saying "but template strings are also vulnerable": [This is not just a regular template string!](https://runkit.com/embed/cjvoqjbt9vnz))

Comment: I wasn't worrying about using prepared statements because ID is a randomly generated value rather than coming from the user so SQL injection is not a problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async function generateAndCheckIdValid() {
  const id = await generateId();
  console.log("ID generated - " + id);
  checkChatIdExists(id)
    .then((validId) => {
      return validId;
    })
    .catch((message) => {
      console.log(message);
      return generateAndCheckIdValid(); //if id does exist then run again
    });
}
```

This async function has no return statement in it, so it's promise will implicitly resolve to `undefined`. There's a return statement in a `.then` callback but that won't do anything of note. I recommend that you don't mix `async`/`await` with `.then` and just stick to one style. Using `async`/`await` the code would be:

```
async function generateAndCheckIdValid() {
  let id = await generateId();
  console.log("ID generated - " + id);
  try {
    const validId = await checkChatIdExists(id);
    return validId;
    // If you prefer, the above 2 lines can be shortened to:
    // return await checkChatIdExists(id);
  } catch (message) {
    console.log(message);
    return generateAndCheckIdValid()
  }
}
```

If you prefer using `.then`, you would write the code like this:

```
function generateAndCheckIdValid() {
  return generateId() // <--- note the `return`
    .then(id => {
       console.log("ID generated - " + id);
       return checkChatIdExists(id);
    })
    // You don't need a .then which just re-returns the value. The promise
    //   is already resolving to that value
    // .then(validId => { return validId })
    .catch(message) => {
      console.log(message);
      return generateAndCheckIdValid();
    });
}
```

Comment: Using the .then method, it is returning the promise object rather than the ID when I run it. How do I get the valid ID from that?

Comment: To access the eventual value of a promise, either `await` the promise, or call `.then` on it. Eg, `let id = await generateAndCheckIdValid();` or `generateAndCheckIdValid().then(id => { ... })`